# Protect directory in apache by only allowing someone with a random generated password to access

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, debian

I am currently busy with a website which basically does the following:

1. someone uploads a file then some processing is done on that file and then the completed file is stored in a directory called /documents.
   Inside of my php script I generate a random number which allows multiple documents to be stored simultaneously, for example a document might be stored in /documents/145214693/file.pdf.
2. The user then has the option to download the document.
3. Inside of my /documents folder I have a .htaccess file which Deny's anyone to access the /documents folder by typing it into the URL bar, for example when someone types www.example.com/documents/ they will receive "Forbidden".

Now the issue is, this also disallows anyone from downloading the file.

Is there a way in which I can generate a random code and inside of my htaccess file I specify that only someone with that specific code is allow to access that specific directory?

In short, when someone uploads a file it is stored in /documents/256984128/test.pdf, then generate a random code which is passed through the URL for ex,

```
www.example.com/documents/256984128/test.pdf?code=<random code here>
```

and only if the code is correct access is granted to the file. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the script generates /documents/145214693/, it can also generate .htaccess file within this folder. In this .htaccess file you can specify what you need.

Comment: Thanks for  the response, so let's say I generate /documents/152478964/ and also generate a .htaccess file and store it inside of the directory (152478964), and I generate a secret code inside of my php, how will my .htaccess file look like, to only allow access via the URL if the secret code is a match?

Comment: If this way is ok for you, either search for info on writing .htaccess file or post a new question.